Creating reverse phi movement illusion on an image file in python
I've been trying to create the reverse phi illusion animation on an object of a specific color in an image file in python. Does anyone know how to do this? or know the algorithm required? Here is an example of the illusion on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Mkewp5NAtg

Python is not a graphic design tool. Ask scripting questions at http://stackoverflow.com

I don't think the python folks would have much knowledge on graphic illusions. Also I said I would settle for the algorithm or an in depth explanation. I will ask there as well though.

Well most graphic designers aren't using Python for anything, unless they grab some packaged script somewhere. Designers just generally have no Python knowledge. And this question is more about an algorithm (as you posted) and Python scripting. The crux is the scripting, not the images.
